# Make rails ignore inputs if user is admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, updates, roles

I have a user object, he can update his profile which includes name, user_name, password (blank), password_confirmation (blank), email, email_confirmation (blank), bio and picture url.

My model states that all of the `(blank)` MUST be filled in. but if your admin and your just going to the users page to update the user's role - You as the admin should not have to fill in user data you obviously don't know.

So how does one get around this? should I instead create a list of users with a drop down beside them? is this not, essentially , a giant form? If so - how would this get created?

essentially: What's the best way to deal with this situation?

**This is currently how users get updated**

```
  def update
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @user.update_attributes(user_update_params)
    if @user.save
      render :show
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def user_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :user_name, :email, :email_confirmation, :password,
      :password_confirmation, :bio, :picture_url, :role)
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem seems to be that you have a logical error in your User model validations.

You seem to have a validation of the form,

```
validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: true
```

which is enforced EVERY TIME, i.e. a new password has to be selected every single time a user object is saved. But this is likely not what you want. You likely want this validation to only be enforced when the user is created for the first time, i.e. when it is a new record.

You can do this with,

```
validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: true, if: :new_record?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update_attribute
```

Updates the attribute without doing validations, you need this one.

check out this [api doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute)

EDIT:

Speaking about reading documentation

Here is an abstract from the [method documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute)

> update_attribute(name, value) public
>
> Updates a single attribute and saves the record. This is especially
>   useful for boolean flags on existing records. Also note that
>
> ```
> Validation is skipped.
>
> Callbacks are invoked.
>
> updated_at/updated_on column is updated if that column is available.
>
> Updates all the attributes that are dirty in this object.
> ```

**EDIT:**

If you still need to validate with this method, note that it says that callbacks are invoked, so what you can do is write your own code to validate input and use callbacks as described [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

Comment: Updated the OP, please explain how I can tell it to do it with out validations - also - if the fields are blank - then will they not save the empty values into the database? I don't want that ... Also validation should always be done ...

Comment: I am confused now.. You are controversing yourself asking to show how you can do this without validations and then saying that validations should always be done... To update a single attribute you just use the method I have mentioned in my answer (update_attribute instead of update_attributes) this will not insert blank spaces into the fields you did not intend to update but only the field you have specified with name/value pair.

Comment: I have just edited in some more info about the method.. hope you will find it helpful

Comment: oh sorry I thought you were talking about update_attributes - appoligies

Comment: I see :) happens it ok. tick the box if you accept the answer please or just go ahead and ask if there is anything needs to be clarified

Comment: Also, edited in how you could possibly still validate input with this method even if it skips default validations. have a look at callbacks